# Determining Control X checkbox Name in VBA

Tags: excel, checkbox, activex, vba

Can someone tell me what the syntax is to determine the controlX checkbox name? 
I have approximately 4 check boxes and this may potentially grow, so I'd like a method of passing through the checkbox name dynamically rather than writing the same execution 4-9 times.

My intention is to pass through the checkbox name as a variable so I do not have to repeat the below code for each checkbox. Also, does anyone know how to reference a named range to a specific checkbox? The code I have so far is:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim strCheck As String
strCheck = CheckBox1.Value

If strCheck = True Then

    Range("RevAssp_CCV").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

   Else
    Range("RevAssp_CCV").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True


End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do note that we are not a 'code-for-you' website. Should you ask for assistance please provide more details like, the things you have done so far, the problems you are encountering. HTH.

Comment: Show us what you have so far! We can't answer your question unless we know what you're talking about, and you need to be way more specific than you think. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it in a userform or in a worksheet?

Comment: It's in a worksheet.  The event hides or un-hides named ranges with the selection.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a custom wrapper class, create an array of objects of said class and then hook into the event there.
You can then (for example) check the Caption and set the "hidden" of the `NamedRange.EntireRow` equal to the value (e.g. checked is invisible, unchecked is visible)

The most basic implementation of this would be as follows:

CustomCheckBox Class module:

```
Private WithEvents p_chkBox As MSForms.checkbox
Public Property Let box(value As MSForms.checkbox)
    Set p_chkBox = value
End Property
Public Property Get box() As MSForms.checkbox
    Set box = p_chkBox
End Property
Private Sub p_chkBox_Click()
    Range(p_chkBox.Caption).EntireRow.Hidden = p_chkBox.value
End Sub
```

And in a regular module:

```
Public cCheckBox() As CustomCheckBox
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim oleObj As OLEObject
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each oleObj In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(oleObj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            ReDim Preserve cCheckBox(0 To i)
            Set cCheckBox(i) = New CustomCheckBox
            cCheckBox(i).box = oleObj.Object
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next oleObj
Next ws
End Sub
```

The regular module puts all checkboxes into 1 array, which is a public variable so it will be available even after the code has run. You could also place this code in the Workbook Module as `Private Sub Workbook_Open` to ensure that the checkboxes will be initialized properly in all cases.

Keep in mind that if the Named Range for the caption of the Checkbox doesn't exist, this will throw errors.

To get back to your example, you could now just add two checkboxes on your sheets and set the caption of the first one to "RevAssp_CCV" and the second one to whatever other named range you wish to toggle.

Comment: Thankyou - the example you've given me is great. I was able to modify my code to get it to run through the event.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking it as answer, so it may help others too.

Comment: Hi Rik - Apologies, new to the site. Am I supposed to mark the question as answered somewhere or just make a comment? thanks

Comment: Mark as answered if the answer helped you and you're the asker. If you think it's a good answer, upvote as well. Upvoting (or downvoting bad answers) also goes for other people's questions.